# Replacing a specific text inside a String/Sentence to a float using Python

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, replace

I have a SQL string from a file something like this:

```
   SELECT a.codeid, a.name, a.order, a.cost, a.nodays
   FROM Table a
   Where a.codeid = 'old_id'
   and a.name = 'myname'
   and a.nodays = 'count_days'
```

Here 'old_id', 'myname' and 'count_days' are dummies which I need to change while running a sql query to real values like 'abcd' for id  'Bishop' for name and 5 (say) for nodays.

I have defined a python function to convert the sql query in the file to a real sql which I want like this ( and after that will use pyodbc to pull the data)

```
    import re 
    def dummyTorealQuery(file, idval, nameval, daysval):
      daysval_st = str(daysval)
      mydict = {'old_id': idval,'myname': nameval,'count_days':daysval_st}
      fr = open(file, 'r')
      real_query = fr.read()
      fr.close()

      for key, value in mydict.items():
          real_query = re.sub(key,value, real_query)


    myquery = dummyTorealQuery(myfile 'abcd', 'Bishop', 5)
```

However, when I get the output it looks like:

```
   SELECT a.codeid, a.name, a.order, a.cost, a.nodays
   FROM Table a
   Where a.codeid = 'abcd'
   and a.name = 'Bishop'
   and a.nodays = '5'
```

The problem is, I do not want the last line as such with 5 enclosed in a string, I want it as

```
   SELECT a.codeid, a.name, a.order, a.cost, a.nodays
   FROM Table a
   Where a.codeid = 'abcd'
   and a.name = 'Bishop'
   and a.nodays = 5
```

How can I achieve that?

I know the post is pretty long, but felt to have a complete discussion if that helps.

***So to put it compactly, I need to replace a specific text inside a string with a float like***:

*** 'Hello world I am going for a vacation for*** *somenumber* *** days' ***

So need to replace the text 'somenumber' in the above with say 30 days to look like ( using python regex or replace or whatever)

*** 'Hello world I am going for a vacation for**  30  **days' ***

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried passing mydict = {'old_id': idval,'myname': nameval,'count_days':int(daysval_st)} ? of float or whatever?

Comment: You can also import ast and then mydict = {'old_id': idval,'myname': nameval,'count_days':ast.literal_eval(daysval_st))}

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code, simply making integer without quotes is easy, just replace the `'` `'` too:

```
def dummyTorealQuery(file, idval, nameval, daysval):
    fr = open(file, 'r')
    real_query = fr.read()
    fr.close()
    return real_query.replace({'old_id': idval,'myname': nameval,"'count_days'":daysval})

myquery = dummyTorealQuery(myfile, 'abcd', 'Bishop', 5)
```

Comment: This did not work.. The output is giving me 'count__days'  instead

Comment: Thanks U-9. This one and the solution from Jason, both worked!

Answer (score -2):

If you want to convert a string representing a float to an actual float, use Python's float method:

```
s = '30.0'
f = float(s)
```

Variable f is now a float.

Comment: But replacing can't replace `str` with `float` nor `int`.

Comment: Yes, but his example is a bit unclear since he's trying to do something in a round-about way. There is no need to do a replace in his example.

Comment: Yes string to float works when you are directly replacing the string to float. I am trying to replace a particular string  inside a string (sentence) to float.

Comment: import re

`>>> re.sub('REPLACE_ME','30','Hello world I am going for a vacation for REPLACE_ME days')` This will return a string with a number in it -- It looks like what you are trying to do is pass a SQL statement with an int / float for comparison. Keep in mind that this and U9-Forward's solution could open you up to SQL injection attacks. 

I am just showing you how to do it.